# why is the headline text not horizontally aligned with the rest of the content?

Tags: html, css, text, footer

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.content1{
  position: relative;
  margin: 130px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.content1 .text{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202020;
}
.content1 .p{
  font-size: 2.1875rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202020;
}
footer{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #111;
}
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  color: #d9d9d9;
}
.main-content .box{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.box h2{
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
.box .content{
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.box .content:before{
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
.box .content:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 15%;
  background: #f12020;
  top: -10px;
}
.left .content p{
  text-align: justify;
}
.left .content .social{
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.left .content .social a{
  padding: 0 2px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
}
.left .content .social a span{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.left .content .social a span:hover{
  background: #f12020;
}
.center .content .fas{
  font-size: 1.4375rem;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.center .content .fas:hover{
  background: #f12020;
}
.center .content .text{
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.center .content .phone{
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.right form .text{
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #656565;
}
.right form .msg{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.right form input, .right form .msgForm{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
}
.right form input:focus,
.right form .msgForm:focus{
  outline-color: #3498db;
}
.right form input{
  height: 35px;
}
.right form .btn{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.right form .btn button{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #f12020;
  font-size: 1.0625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
.right form .btn button:hover{
  background: #000;
}
.bottom center{
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  background: #151515;
}
.bottom center span{
  color: #656565;
}
.bottom center a{
  color: #f12020;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.bottom center a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  footer{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  .main-content{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .main-content .box{
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<footer>
      <div class="main-content" id="contact">
        <div class="left box">
          <h2>About us</h2>
<div class="content">
            <p>
this is the story of my life</p>
<div class="social">
              <a href="https://facebook.com/coding.np"><span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span></a>
              <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a>
              <a href="https://instagram.com/coding.np"><span class="fab fa-instagram"></span></a>
              <a href="https://youtube.com/c/codingnepal"><span class="fab fa-youtube"></span></a>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="center box">
          <h2>
Address</h2>
<div class="content">
            <div class="place">
              <span class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></span>
              <span class="text">Birendranagar, Surkhet</span>
            </div>
<div class="phone">
              <span class="fas fa-phone-alt"></span>
              <span class="text">+089-765432100</span>
            </div>
<div class="email">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
              <span class="text">abc@example.com</span>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="right box">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="email">
            <div class="text">Email *</div>
            <input type="email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="msg">
            <div class="text">Message *</div>
            <textarea id=".msgForm" rows="2" cols="25" required></textarea>
          </div>
              <br/>
          <div class="btn">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <center>
              <span class="far fa-copyright"></span> 2020 All rights reserved.
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

[image of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POF3R.png)

I have 3 containers for the footer. Each Container has content(more containers) in it that is all aligned at the center of the container "content". there is also h2 text which is not aligned to the rest of the content. how can i align the h2 text so that it starts the text just as my content of container"content? i tried it with text-align: center; but it's not aligned. i also tried to cut out all the single css container styles but it didn't change the position of the content from the container"content". somebody can help?

Comment: can you rephrase your question or show a diagram of what you want?

Comment: The code snippet does not match the footer image provided, ie it lines up fine in the snippet. Is there some other CSS interfering that has not been included above?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and also run in my browser it is correct and also your h2 align with rest of your content, But still if you want change alignment of heading you can use **flex** property and **justify-content** to change align

```
.box h2{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

Please let me know if still there is an any issue and correct me, Hope so your code will execute properly